# sendResponse in a getAuthToken callback doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with using sendResponse from my background script to my popup script. I have discovered that the problem concerns that I am trying to sendResponse from within the getAuthToken callback. How do I get around this?

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.task == "auth") {
      chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
        'interactive': true
      }, function(token) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
          return;
        }
      })

      var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
      x.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + token);

      x.onload = function() {
        if (x.readyState = 200) {
          var data = this.responseText;
          jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
          sendResponse({
            response: jsonResponse
          }); //return the email to the popup
          return true;
        };
      }
      x.send();
    }; //end of auth
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return `true` from the callback you pass to addListener to be able to use sendResponse from asynchronously running code. Here it is in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#simple)

> In the above example, sendResponse was called synchronously. If you want to asynchronously use sendResponse, add return true; to the onMessage event handler.